# Underline placeholder in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, underline

How can I underline placeholder in iOS in React Native? I can underline whole `TextInput` (not placeholder) by:

```
borderBottomWidth: 1,
borderBottomColor: '#B8B8B8',
```

[image]

I would like to underline only placeholder of `TextInput`, not `TextInput`

Comment: I do not know react native, but i can let you know how you can achieve this, if you want.

Comment: @dahiya_boy let me know please, I will try to add it into React Native

Comment: Get the textwidth , here is `€0` now according to that set you underline width. Thats what we do in native ios, may be it will also same available in react.

Comment: @dahiya_boy Thanks for the hint, but I think it doesn't work in react native.

Comment: Are you wanting the placeholder underline to stick around while the user is interacting with the TextInput, or would it hide when they start typing?

Comment: @chapeljuice it would hide when start typing, but would be great if you can cover both use-cases :)

Comment: @Matt i would appreciate some feedback on my below  answer

Comment: @TimH I actually did something similar, but anyway I really appreciate your help. If better answer doesn't show up than yours within 2 days, I will award and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little workaround for you. As soon as you start typing, the underline gets removed.

**Demo**

[image: iphone 6 demo]

[image: iphone 7 plus demoe]

**Explanation**

I applied the `borderBottomWidth` and `borderBottomColor` to the parent view, because you probably don't want to use `multiline`. If you want to use a mulitine TextInput you could apply those styles directly to the Textinput, as mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html).

> Note that some props are only available with multiline={true/false}.
>   Additionally, border styles that apply to only one side of the element
>   (e.g., borderBottomColor, borderLeftWidth, etc.) will not be applied
>   if multiline=false. To achieve the same effect, you can wrap your
>   TextInput in a View

As soon as the user has typed (the text length is greater than 0) something,  `this.setState({ active: true })` gets fired. After that the conditional rendering takes place here:

```
borderBottomColor: this.state.active === false ? 'red' : 'transparent' // hide color, when text is present
width: this.state.active === false ? scaledWidth : 100 // increase width to 100. Value is just a placeholder, use whatever you like
```

**Complete Code**

```
// helper function to scale font size and placeholder width.
scale = (fontSize) => {
    const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width; 
    const ratio = fontSize / 375; // get ratio based on your standard scale, here: width of iphone 7
    const newSize = Math.round(ratio * screenWidth);
    return newSize; 
  }


render() {
   // you probably have to play around with those standard values 
   const scaledFontSize = this.scale(22); 
   const scaledWidth = this.scale(25);    
   return (
      <View style={{ marginTop: 50, flex: 1, alignItems: 'flex-end' }}>
         <View style={{ borderBottomWidth: 2, borderBottomColor: this.state.active === false ? 'red' : 'transparent', width: this.state.active === false ? scaledWidth : 100  }}>
             <TextInput
             style={{ height: 30,  textAlign: 'right', fontSize: scaledFontSize }}
             onChangeText={(text) => text.length > 0 ? this.setState({ active: true }) : this.setState({ active: false })}
             placeholder={'10'}
             //multiline 
             />
        </View>
     </View>
   )
}
```